# What is a good way to calculate geographical distances in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, gis, haversine, geographic-distance

I want to get distance from the database entry;
I've tried the below code so far

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere( POINT(LNG1, LAT1), POINT(LNG2,LNG2) )* .000621371 ;
```

Though I've gotten a result, I'm not sure its accurate.
I've compared my results with this website
(https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml)

NOTE: I am trying to get it in miles.

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere( POINT(-73.98568175135509, 40.7484381443023), POINT(-77.53989898824496, 38.993292463424126) )* .000621371 ; gives a result. ` 224.08790255056905`
```

is an example. it gives 224
while the website gave 196

Comment: How far off is it from the website?

Comment: Sometimes its close like 1.96 to 2mi from the website.
Another example showed me 32mi to 28mi

Comment: The web site says that the results are approximate. Although I can't imagine why it would use a different formula.

Comment: You could implement the Haversine formula yourself.

Comment: Please edit the question with example input and output.

Comment: SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere( POINT(-73.98568175135509, 40.7484381443023), POINT(-77.53989898824496, 38.993292463424126) )* .000621371 ;

gives a result. ` 224.08790255056905` while the website shows 194mi. If there is another website thats showing a different that would be helpful. 

I have applied haversine before. Im trying to be as mysql pure as possible just for this approach.

Comment: Edit the question, not a comment.

Comment: [this site](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) agrees with MySQL. 360.5 km = 224 miles

Comment: Alright, thanks, for the site link. its coming close so far.

Answer (score 2):

The website you used also reports 224 miles - it is just being nautical site, it defaults to nautical miles (n mi), and that gives you 196 n mi. Make sure you select `sm` (statute miles - or regular miles), you get 224 sm.

Answer (score 0):

ST_Distance_Sphere does employ Haversine internally.
The website linked in the question was using `nmi` instead of `mi`, i.e. nautical miles instead of miles.